# Posterior Predictive Distribution as Expectation of Likelihood

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, posterior

Say we have a posterior predictive density:

$$p(\tilde{y}|\mathbf{y}) = \int p(\tilde{y}|\theta)p(\theta|\mathbf{y})d\theta$$

In Hoff's Bayesian Statistical Methods text, he suggests that to obtain an approximation of $p(\tilde{y}|\mathbf{y})$ by sampling from posterior distribution, and computing $\frac{1}{S}\sum_{s=1}^Sp(\tilde{y}|\theta^{(s)})$.

He justifies this by stating $p(\tilde{y} | \mathbf{y})$ is the posterior expectation of $p(\tilde{y}|\theta)$, but I actually can't see the equivalence. How does one derive $p(\tilde{y} | \mathbf{y})$ from $p(\tilde{y}|\theta)$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf y}$We have 
$$
E_{\theta|\y}\left[f(\theta)\right] = \int f(\theta) p(\theta | \y)\,\text d\theta
$$
just by definition of expectation (and you could cite the [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) as well), and since $p(\theta|\y)$ is the posterior density this is the posterior expectation of $f(\theta)$. Now choose 
$$
f(\theta) = p(\tilde y | \theta)
$$
and then
$$
E_{\theta|\y}\left[p(\tilde y | \theta)\right] = \int p(\tilde y | \theta) p(\theta | \y)\,\text d\theta.
$$

I'm not sure if you also are wondering about the justification of this integral in the first place, but typically the data are assumed independent given the generating parameters so for a new point $\tilde y$ you'd have $\tilde y \perp \y | \theta$ which means
$$
p(\tilde y | \y) = \int p(\tilde y , \theta | \y)\,\text d\theta \\
= \int p(\tilde y | \theta , \y) p(\theta | \y)\,\text d\theta \\
= \int p(\tilde y | \theta) p(\theta | \y)\,\text d\theta \\
= E_{\theta|\y}\left[p(\tilde y | \theta)\right]
$$

so you can use the law of large numbers with posterior samples to produce an estimator of this density.

Comment: To compute $p(\tilde{y}|y)$, first sample from $\tilde{y}$ from the data distribution and then for this $\tilde{y}$, continuously sample $\theta^{(i)}$ from the posterior distribution and compute $p(\tilde{y}|\theta)$ ? how does the expectation scalar quantity be turned to a probability distribution for $p(\tilde{y}|y)$ ?